# Sharepoint https and host header

Tags: web-application, https, host-header

Not a long time ago I was requested to create a new sharepoint web app to host our new portal. Because this portal would be (at the time) our only web app running in this farm and because the boss told me to, i used the port 80.

We use the domain xpto.com

Now the boss wants to create a "employee-only" web site for colaboration at "portal.xpto.com". This new site have to use HTTPS.

To do it I created a new web application at port 80 using the host header portal.xpto.com and checked the "https" box. Everything went fine with the web app and the site collection creation.

When i browsed "Https:// portal.xpto.com" (pls igone the extra space) I ended up being redirected to "http:// xpto.com". So i went to the host IIS and saw that my new website was sttoped. When I hit "start" the site wont go up saying that port 80 is already being used. Isn't host header supposed to managed this?!? what should I do?

Comment: by website do you mean a site collection with different sub-webs in it or just a single page

Comment: @TimeToShine by site I mean a web application, because this "site" is not anonymous enabled...

Comment: Your post is a little unclear - are you trying to have SSL-enabled traffic go over port 80?

Comment: @JesseC im not really sure of what i want. I know what i need to accomplish... i might be asking "the wrong question" so I did my best to explain what the end results need to be... i edited the post anyway futher explaning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the HTTPS Employee host header off of 80. Because HTTPS is required, no one should be using the TCP port for that site.

Go to Start -> Adminsitrative Tools -> IIS Manager -> Expand server -> Expand Sites -> Click on your HTTPS site -> Bindings... -> Highlight Http -> Edit... -> Change port to port 81. Also make sure port https has a certificate installed onto it. It should NOT say "Not Selected" (Do this same procedure for the http site that is broken to make sure it's running on port 80)

Click OK and OK again.

Perform an IISReset. Start -> Run... -> type CMD.exe -> Rightclick -> Start as administrator -> Type in "iisreset"

After this your websites should come up fine.

Comment: im not sure i followed you here... you want me to change both of the sites in the IIS to port 81? or just the broken one? Because the "old" site is running just fine... shoudn't I move only the broken one?

Comment: yes move the broken one to port 81, just for Http and https should be port 443

Answer (score 1):

> Open the Central administration console —-> Application
>   Management—>create or extend web application
>
> Click create a new web application –> fill all the fields & select
>   port number as 80 and fill the host header.
>
> Click ok to proceed for site creation. In this way you can create
>   multiple sites running on port 80.

If this way doesn't work let me know, and also are you using a Wildcard SSL certificate since you want both websites on 443 (https) if not [this article will help you.](http://milapshah.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/host-multiple-websites-using-ssl-on.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: i did as you said the first time around... and as i said in the post the website is not running because iis reports that theres already an site on that port...